# r shiny - display data frame after uploading

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a record linkage app in R shiny.  I have been using R for a while but am new to shiny.  My problem is I am struggling to figure out how to display the file I upload via `fileInput`.  My code is below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
```

### ui

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Record Linkage App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      ## Tab 1 -- Specify Task
      menuItem("Select Task And Upload Files", tabName = "task", icon = 
    icon("file-text-o")),
  ## Tab 2 -- View Raw Data Files
  menuItem("View Raw Data", tabName = "raw", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
  ## Tab 3 -- View Processed Data Files
  menuItem("View Processed Data", tabName = "processed", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
  ## Tab 4 -- Select Training Set
  menuItem("Select Training Set", tabName = "mltrain", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
  ## Tab 5 -- View Weight & Probabilities (choose which chart to view or both?)
  menuItem("Visualize Distributions", tabName = "distributions", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
  ## Tab 6 -- View Results (review, match and trash files--need to be able to choose dataset)
  ## Want to be able to add checkboxes to select rows for inclusion in deletion later on
  menuItem("View Result Files", tabName = "fileview", icon = icon("file-text-o"))

)), # close dashboard sidebar

  #### Dashboard Body starts here

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
  ### Specify Task & Upload Files Tab
  tabItem(tabName = "task",
          radioButtons("task", "Select a Task:", c("Frame Deduplication", "Frame Record Linkage")),
          fileInput("selection", "Upload Files:", multiple = T, 
                    accept = c(".xls", "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain", ".csv")),
          helpText(paste("Please upload a file.  Supported file types are:  .txt, .csv and .xls"))

          ), # close first tabItem

  tabItem(tabName = "raw",
          helpText(paste("This tab displays the raw, unprocessed data frames selected in the previous tab.")),
          mainPanel(
            tableOutput("contents")

          )

) # close tabItems

  ) # close dashboardBody
) #close dashboardpage
```

)

### server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$contents <- renderTable({
      req(input$file1)
      read.csv(input$file1$datapath)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to be able to display the table in the tab "raw".

My question is:  1.  If I just want to display the table does it need to be `reactive`?
2.  How does `input$file1$datapath` enter into `renderTable`?

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The [reference document for `fileInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html) has an example that shows exactly how to use the data once uploaded. It's a little outdated (e.g., should be using `req(input$file1)` instead of `is.null(...)`), but it should still work fine. (Also available with `?fileInput` on your local console.)

Comment: The problem is I want to display the data table in the second tab, not the first.  The example given doesn't work

Comment: The `server` component does not delineate or care in which tab a UI element is contained. If you write `output$contents <- renderTable(...)` anywhere within `server`, then it will be displayed in your second tab, `"raw"`. You say it doesn't work but don't show code that attempts it, please update your `server` code (that includes `renderTable`).

Comment: Must have missed that in my tutorials.  Valuable info.  I updated the code to what I ran to include `renderTable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're taking the documentation a little too literally: you should be referencing `input$selection`, not `input$file1`. I modified your server component to this, and it worked:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(input$selection)
    read.csv(input$selection$datapath)
  })
}
```

BTW: though not harming things, you are using `mainPanel`, which is usually used in a non-dashboard app along with `shiny::sidebarLayout`. Since you're using `shinydashboard`, though, it is unnecessary, and you can reduce the last `tabItem` to just

```r
      tabItem(tabName = "raw",
              helpText(paste("This tab displays the raw, unprocessed data frames selected in the previous tab.")),
              tableOutput("contents")
              )
```

Comment: oh I see.  Thanks so much.  I guess I was using `input$file1` because I had planned on being able to upload multiple files at once, hence the `multiple = T`.

Comment: It might help to add a `browser()` after `req(input$selection)` in the `renderTable` block. From there, when you select multiple files, take a look at `input$selection` and see for your self what it looks like. (Spoiler: it's a `data.frame` with one row per uploaded file, so `input$selection[1]` is reasonable for the first of 1 or more files.)