# How to render a tableoutput in another tab in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a simple website using `Shiny`,that allow users to uplaod a csv,xls ... file within `Getting the data` tab and view it in another tab named `Viewing the data` and then plot that data in another tab `visualizing the data` . for instance i want just to render a table based on the data picked ,

Here's a snippet of what i tried :

**`ui`** :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("APRIORI INPUTS",id="panelTitle"),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(title = "Getting the data",icon = icon("database"), 
                   tags$div(id="uploadFiles",
                            fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                                      multiple = TRUE,
                                      accept = c("text/csv",
                                                 "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                 ".csv"))
                   )

                 ), 
        tabPanel(title = "Viewing the data",icon = icon("eye"),
                 tableOutput("Viewing_the_data")), 
        tabPanel(title = "visualizing the data",icon = icon("chart-bar"),
                 tableOutput("visualizing_the_data"))
      )
    ),
  )
)
```

for the server logic :

**`server`** :

```
server <- function(input, output){
  output$Viewing_the_data <- renderTable({
    req(input$uploadFiles)
    read.csv(input$selection$datapath)

  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried that but doesn't work ...

PS : i tried that with `shinydashboard` and it works perfectly as that : [r shiny - display data frame after uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543482/r-shiny-display-data-frame-after-uploading)

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might get some ideas from here: https://mastering-shiny.org/action-transfer.html#uploading-data. It doesn't have tabs, but I don't see how tabs in the `ui` will affect this example - should work just as fine.

Comment: Thank you @ValeriVoev ,i appreciate that ! But i haven't any problem on loading and displaying the data within the same tab ( as where the user upload it) ... The server logic i  made seems to me working but i get unexpected result .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to adapt the example I [mentioned](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-transfer.html#uploading-data) with your app, removing some of the complexity to make it a simpler app but still have the tabbed structure and it works when I run it. I can choose the file in one tab, select how many rows to show in the sidebar and show the data in another tab:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel("APRIORI INPUTS",id="panelTitle",
                     numericInput("n", "Rows", value = 5, min = 1, step = 1)),
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel(title = "Getting the data", fileInput("file", NULL, accept = c(".csv", ".tsv")), icon = icon("database")), 
                tabPanel(title = "Viewing the data", tableOutput("head"), icon = icon("eye")))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive({
        req(input$file)

        ext <- tools::file_ext(input$file$name)
        switch(ext,
               csv = vroom::vroom(input$file$datapath, delim = ","),
               tsv = vroom::vroom(input$file$datapath, delim = "\t"),
               validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv or .tsv file")
        )
    })

    output$head <- renderTable({
        head(data(), input$n)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks so much, So can i use the same approach to forward  the data to the other tab ? (I'm working on a project for the university and i get pressed by time) . Thank you again!  you save me a lot of time !